# How to catch 'jingling traffic bot' traffic in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-traffic

I have find out from the windows registry url that one of my junior was using jingling traffic bot to manage fake traffic to website. After a research I find out that after putting google as reference he was managing organic hits. 
But still I am unable to filter out traffic on google analytic. I am trying to find a method by which I can filter(or stop) bot traffic on showing on google analytics.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few dimensions I look at when hunting bot traffic are as follows. These can be viewed in various reports as well as creating segments and filters.

1. Hostname

   - Was your site on your server actually visited?
2. Source

   - Is the bot trying to spoof a campaign using a forced source/medium?
3. Referral

   - Is the bot attempting to get traffic back to its own site?
4. Browser/Network

   - Is there anything in the browser/network data that implies bot traffic?
5. Geolocation

   - Is the traffic coming from expected locations? If not, look into why. This would be the least granular method.

Some more specifics might be helpful to get a better tailored answer to your specific issue- like if he was sending lots of traffic, what is the common dimension behind those hits?

I made a custom report that you can find in the Gallery (Customization > Import From Gallery > Search for "Spambot Hunting"). This might help illuminate some clues for you.

Comment: I have tried Spambot hunting but I didn't helped me out as I am taking traffic from multiple referrals. Rest Source and Hostname didn't work out for me. Only one thing that I found was that there were no keywords for fake traffic jingling. In place of keywords google was showing "(not provided)". No other clue that I found to track fake traffic

Answer (score -1):

Most of the the time Bots Provides Direct Traffic like Jingling. It's very hard to filter these types of traffic on google analytics. In this case you will need to filter out other dimensions for different patterns like large companies uses bots to filter these by analysing Unique Service Provider and Languages would also be the helpful dimension to check out.
Bounce Rate also.

Jingling is risky but you can improve alexa rank.

[Habiio.com - Jingling Google Analytics](http://habiio.com/improve-alexa-rank-with-jingling-and-traffic-spirit-bot/)